# How can I create a dynamic chat in a Discord.js bot?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

With this I mean a chat like the React for Roles bot one: when you execute the command `rr!reactionrole` in order to create a new reaction role, it asks you to input a channel, and AFTER you have answered in a completely new message, the bot´s message is edited and you have to answer the new question in another new message. How is that possible? I hope I have explained myself correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js has a method that can be used for this very purpose, [`MessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector). Once you set it up to a `TextChannel`, it'll collect messages, depending on the [`CollectorFilter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorFilter) and [`MessageCollectorOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageCollectorOptions).

That is to get the answers, but to seamlessly edit the original question message, it is simply using the [`Message#edit()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) upon a stored message ID method.

For instance:

```
const questions = ['What role?', 'What message?', 'What emoji?'];

const question = await message.channel.send(questions[0]); // store the question message object to a constant to be used later

const filter = msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id; // creates the filter where it will only look for messages sent by the message author
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 60 * 1000 }); // creates a message collector with a time limit of 60 seconds - upon that, it'll emit the 'end' event

const answers = []; // basic way to store to the answers, for this example

collector.on('collect', msg => { // when the collector finds a new message
  answers.push(msg.content);
  questions.shift();
  if (questions.length <= 0) return collector.stop('done'); // sends a string so we know the collector is done with the answers
  question.edit(questions[0]).catch(error => { // catch the error if the question message was deleted - or you could create a new question message
    console.error(error);
    collector.stop();
  });
});

collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
  if (reason && reason === 'stop') {
    // when the user has answered every question, do some magic
  }
  message.channel.send('You did not answer all the questions in time or the original message was deleted!');
});
```

Note: I have not tested this, and it's not very well made, but you should be able to adapt it to your use. I suggest to [read this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html) that'll explain more about async collectors and more fun stuff!

Answer (score 0):

A way this can be implemented in a sense is to keep a 'state' for every channel the bot reads messages from. The idea would be that whenever the bot gets a new message from a certain channel, it first checks if it is already in the middle of a conversation. Depending on the value of this state, and the input, the bot does the appropriate action.

```
var state = 0;

//on rr!reactionrole
{
switch(state) {
 case 0: //start the conversation and change the state to 1; break;
 case 1: //continue the conversation, edit the message, set state to 2; break;
 //other cases
}
}
```